# Soql query on parents other child object

Tags: soql, query, master-detail

I want to write a soql query , My scenario is as follows. I have three objects objectA,objectB,objectC. objectA is the parent object for both objectB,objectC.

- objectA - objectB  (Master-detail relationship)
- objectA - objectC  (Master-detail relationship)`

ObjectB has two fields:

- Start_date__c
- End_date__c

ObjectC has a field:

- Date__c

Now i want to retrieve records with date__c in objectC those were in between start_date__c and end_date__c of objectB. how can i achieve such functionality .

Comment: Is there always exactly one ObjectB record on an ObjectA? Or are you dealing with a specific ObjectB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to query the junction object like this:

```
Select ObjectC__r.Id, ObjectC__r.Name
From ObjectA__c
Where ObjectC__r.Date__c >= ObjectB__r.start_date__c
And ObjectC__r.Date__c <= ObjectB__r.end_date__c
```

Comment: the `__r` syntax in your example is referencing the child (many) side of the relationship and isn't valid.